# Не могу сделать аккаунт разработчика

Tags: ios, apple

[image]

Ни как не могу аккаунт завести. Уже что только в эти поля не писал все равно пишет, что это ошибка. Мои данные я уже писал всякими способами. Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: А $100 оплатили, за право именоваться Apple Developer?

Comment: Да конечно

Answer (score 3):

А настоящий адрес ввести пробовали? У меня работает например Saint-Petersburg state: Leningrad address: nevskii prospekt, 1, zip/postal 191000

Comment: дак а он настоящие, что вас смущает в нем? Кому интересно проблема была решена использование браузера Сафари под Win!